# How to do postInsert in Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a table (call it Table A) that needs to create multiple additional child records when a Table A record is created. Deleting the Table A record should delete the Table B records.

Deleting the records is easy using `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `schema.yml`, but adding the records is not all that simple. Overriding `Doctrine_Record::postInsert` doesn't do it because the Table A record doesn't have an ID yet. Overriding `Doctrine_Form` save doesn't do it, either.

Is an `EventListener` the way to go or a database trigger? If the former, do you have an example? If the latter, can the trigger be specified somehow in `schema.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `postInsert` doesn't work?

I use this snippet in one of my project (inside the `Table.class.php`):

```
public function postInsert($event)
{
  $dispatcher = ProjectConfiguration::getActive()->getEventDispatcher();
  $dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'item.new', array(
    'item' => $this
  )));
}
```

I spread an event about a new item. Then, I catch this event in my configuration:

```
class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configure()
  {
    // [....]
    $this->dispatcher->connect('item.new', array('shareEvents', 'postToSocial'));
```

And in my `shareEvents` class I access the item id without any problems:

```
class shareEvents
{
  static public function postToSocial(sfEvent $event)
  {
    $item = $event['item'];

    $queue = new AutopostQueue();
    $queue->setItemId($item->getId());
    $queue->save();
```

By the way, you can do your action in a trigger too. But I don't think you can define a trigger inside the `schema.yml` since Doctrine parse it to generate model, form, etc .. But you can define a `trigger.sql` file inside `/data/sql` directory and it will be automatically loaded when you will call:

```
php symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```